# Set Form Control with ngbDatePicker in Subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, ng-bootstrap

I need to set a form control with ngbDatePicker when I get the user data from a GET request, this is the Input:

```html
 <input
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="birthDate"
  [placement]="'bottom'"
  class="form-control"
  id="birthdate"
  [maxDate]="maxDate"
  placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
  name="birthdate"
  [minDate]="{ year: 1940, month: 1, day: 1 }"
  ngbDatepicker
  #d="ngbDatepicker"
  formControlName="birthdate"
  [ngClass]="{
  'is-invalid': !personalData.get('birthdate').valid && personalData.get('birthdate').touched
  }"
  (click)="d.toggle()"
/>
```

The date format is ok, but the value reset the state because is in a subscribe function I guess. The formGroup code:

```
this.personalData = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', null],
  motherName: ['', Validators.required],
  secondLastName: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
  phoneNumber: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$/)]],
  gender: ['male', Validators.required],
  birthdate: [null, Validators.required],
  ufBirth: [null, null],
  municipalityBirth: [null, null],
  nacionality: ['', Validators.required],
  originCountry: [null, null],
  inmigrationDate: ['', null],
  breed: [null, Validators.required],
  education: [null, null],
  familySituation: [null, null],
  cep: ['', Validators.required],
  uf: [null, Validators.required],
  city: [null, Validators.required],
  neighborhood: ['', Validators.required],
  street: ['', Validators.required],
  streetNumber: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[0-9])/)]],
});

birthDate: NgbDateStruct;

this.birthDate = {
      year: moment(user.personalData.birthdate).year(),
      month: moment(user.personalData.birthdate).month(),
      day: moment(user.personalData.birthdate).day(),
    };
    this.personalData.get('birthdate').setValue({
      year: moment(user.personalData.birthdate).year(),
      month: moment(user.personalData.birthdate).month(),
      day: moment(user.personalData.birthdate).day(),
    });
```

I tries several times to set the value to works correctly, I mean 1. get the value formatted, 2. set the value and 3. apply the form validation.

Comment: Your' using RectiveForms, so **remove** the [(ngModel)] in the input

Comment: If I remove it, the form validation don't work properly :(

Comment: Cristian, when you use ReactiveForms, the validation is the indicate when you create the FormGroup. check if you has the input enclosed in a `<form [formGroup]="personalData">`. I made a simple stackblitz in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8avat4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts -I simulate the "call" making a function that return an Observable in the own component. In a real application you should have a service that return a observable